# How to retrieve the Y axis probability values from probplot, Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I m trying to retrieve the actual y axis data ( probabilty %) from probplot handle, but I am not getting the values that I need. Instead it gives me the quantile values

```
% sample data 
data =[68391;54744;54682;71629;42610;54371;37500;41222;39767;65042;54706;15108;57000;55460;73360]';

% obtain the probability plot for data
h1=probplot('lognormal',data,'noref');

% retrieve the y axis data from h1
[sorted_data, indices]= sort(data);
prob(indices)=h1.YData;

% the prob values are not the actual probability values that we see in the
% plot but quantile values , how to directly retrive the probabaility
% values
```

I would like the probability values which we see in the plot. check the values in the prob vector in the sample code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Alternatively compute the probabilities from the quantiles values.
- **Probabilities** shown on the y-axis are based on the **_normal
  cumulative density function**_(`normcdf()`) of the quantiles.

> **Plot**
>
> [image]

---

**Code to retrieve the probability**

```
% sample data 
data = [68391; 54744; 54682; 71629; 42610; 54371; 37500; 41222; ...
        39767; 65042; 54706; 15108; 57000; 55460; 73360]';

% obtain the probability plot for data
h1 = probplot('lognormal',data,'noref');

% quantiles
quantiles = h1.YData;

% probability 
Probability = normcdf(quantiles);

% rearrange according to the order of data 
prob = zeros(size(data));
[sorted_data, indices] = sort(data);
prob(indices) = Probability;
```

---

**`prob.'`**

```
    0.8333
    0.5667
    0.4333
    0.9000
    0.3000
    0.3667
    0.1000
    0.2333
    0.1667
    0.7667
    0.5000
    0.0333
    0.7000
    0.6333
    0.9667
```